# boost.log meanings and functions

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am making code to convert python application to c++.
I am working on logging now.
I use boost log ..but i find some things really difficult to understand
i'm trying to make separate files for each section of my code so that main function remains clean.

When i do this with boost log ,every thing work well but defining
"or declaring or initializing.....these three words are easy to understand with built in types but very difficult to know what it means when using library classes...or may be my brain is not suitable to learn programming"
defining the loggers in the logger file is not seen in main file"although when i define logger in main file but other components like sinks and core  outside main file every thing goes well

simply i wanna know why i must define logger in main although every other component is defined outside main??
do this has something to do with new "i really try to avoid memory arranging because i have so much fear to be stuck there"

i am editing the question to show the problem more clearly
in c++2.cpp i make function init_logger()which return void
in this function i define sinks ,core, attributes and they persist after returning from function"why they persist??"

```
//make attribute argument
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_channel, "Channel", std::string)//????????????
void init_file_collecting(boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink)
{
    sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(
        keywords::target = "logs",                      /*< the target directory >*/
        keywords::max_size = 16 * 1024 * 1024,          /*< maximum total size of the stored files, in bytes >*/
        keywords::min_free_space = 100 * 1024 * 1024,   /*< minimum free space on the drive, in bytes >*/
        keywords::max_files = 7                       /*< maximum number of stored files >*/
    ));
}

boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();
    /*
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_0(keywords::channel = "0");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_1(keywords::channel = "1");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_2(keywords::channel = "2");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_3(keywords::channel = "3");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_4(keywords::channel = "4");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_5(keywords::channel = "5");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_6(keywords::channel = "6");
    */
    core->add_global_attribute("ThreadID", boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id());
    core->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp",attrs::local_clock());
    core->add_global_attribute("RecordID", attrs::counter< unsigned int >(1));
    logging::add_common_attributes();

    //lg_chan_0(keywords::channel = "net");

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink0(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "first_date_with_404.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));
sink0->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "0");
init_file_collecting(sink0);
sink0->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );
core->add_sink(sink0);
```

but when i define loggers in init_function() they dont persist after returning  and the compiler tell me they are undefined
why the core and sinks do persist after return and can be used by logmacros defined in c++2.cpp but the loggers dont  persist?

```
    /*
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_0(keywords::channel = "0");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_1(keywords::channel = "1");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_2(keywords::channel = "2");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_3(keywords::channel = "3");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_4(keywords::channel = "4");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_5(keywords::channel = "5");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_6(keywords::channel = "6");
    */
```

here is the code:

## c++2.cpp

```
// c++2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.


#include "stdafx.h"
#include "program_options_1.h"
#include "utils_logger.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //1 init program_options and configure it
    po::variables_map vm =init_program_options(argc, argv);
    //2 init logger and configure it
    init_logging();
    //3

    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_0(keywords::channel = "0");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_1(keywords::channel = "1");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_2(keywords::channel = "2");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_3(keywords::channel = "3");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_4(keywords::channel = "4");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_5(keywords::channel = "5");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_6(keywords::channel = "6");

    BOOST_LOG(lg_chan_0) << "Hello world0!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg_chan_1) << "Hello world1!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg_chan_2) << "Hello world2!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg_chan_3) << "Hello world3!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg_chan_4) << "Hello world4!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg_chan_5) << "Hello world5!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg_chan_6) << "Hello world6!";
    return 0;
}
```

## utils_logger.h

```
#pragma once
/*
*          Copyright Andrey Semashev 2007 - 2015.
* Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
*    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
*          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
*/

#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>

#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/current_thread_id.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/formatters/format.hpp>

#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_channel_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>

#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
/*
1-first date with 404
2-first date with 200
3-dates with zero size after first date with 200
4-dates of saturday and sunday after first date with 200
5-dates not saturday or sunday after first date with 200 and having zero size
6-dates not saturday or sunday after first date with 200 and having 400
7-last date recieved and written to file

*/
//make attribute argument
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_channel, "Channel", std::string)//????????????

// Complete sink type
typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_file_backend > file_sink;

//[ example_sinks_xml_file_collecting
void init_file_collecting(boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink)
{
    sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(
        keywords::target = "logs",                      /*< the target directory >*/
        keywords::max_size = 16 * 1024 * 1024,          /*< maximum total size of the stored files, in bytes >*/
        keywords::min_free_space = 100 * 1024 * 1024,   /*< minimum free space on the drive, in bytes >*/
        keywords::max_files = 7                       /*< maximum number of stored files >*/
    ));
}
//]

#if 0
//[ example_sinks_xml_file
// Complete file sink type
typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_file_backend > file_sink;

void write_header(sinks::text_file_backend::stream_type& file)
{
    file << "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<log>\n";
}

void write_footer(sinks::text_file_backend::stream_type& file)
{
    file << "</log>\n";
}

void init_logging()
{
    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.xml",  /*< the resulting file name pattern >*/
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384                 /*< rotation size, in characters >*/
    ));

    sink->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("\t<record id=\"%1%\" timestamp=\"%2%\">%3%</record>")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::xml_decor[expr::stream << expr::smessage]            /*< the log message has to be decorated, if it contains special characters >*/
    );

    // Set header and footer writing functors
    sink->locked_backend()->set_open_handler(&write_header);
    sink->locked_backend()->set_close_handler(&write_footer);

    // Add the sink to the core
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}
//]
#endif

//[ example_sinks_xml_file_final
void init_logging()
{
    boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();
    /*
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_0(keywords::channel = "0");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_1(keywords::channel = "1");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_2(keywords::channel = "2");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_3(keywords::channel = "3");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_4(keywords::channel = "4");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_5(keywords::channel = "5");
    src::channel_logger<std::string> lg_chan_6(keywords::channel = "6");
    */
    core->add_global_attribute("ThreadID", boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id());
    core->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp",attrs::local_clock());
    core->add_global_attribute("RecordID", attrs::counter< unsigned int >(1));
    logging::add_common_attributes();

    //lg_chan_0(keywords::channel = "net");

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink0(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "first_date_with_404.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink1(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "first_date_with_200.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink2(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "dates_with_zero_size_after_first_date_with_200.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink3(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "dates_of_saturday_and_sunday_after_first_date_with_200.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink4(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "dates_not_saturday_or_sunday_after_first_date_with_200_having_zero_size.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink5(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "dates_not_saturday_or_sunday_after_first_date_with_200_having_400.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));

    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink6(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "last_date_recieved_and_written_to_file.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));
    /*
    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.xml",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));
    */
    sink0->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "0");
    sink1->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "1");
    sink2->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "2");
    sink3->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "3");
    sink4->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "4");
    sink5->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "5");
    sink6->set_filter(expr::attr< std::string >("Channel") == "6");



    // Set up where the rotated files will be stored
    init_file_collecting(sink0);
    init_file_collecting(sink1);
    init_file_collecting(sink2);
    init_file_collecting(sink3);
    init_file_collecting(sink4);
    init_file_collecting(sink5);
    init_file_collecting(sink6);

    // Upon restart, scan the directory for files matching the file_name pattern
    sink0->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    sink1->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    sink2->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    sink3->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    sink4->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    sink5->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    sink6->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();

    sink0->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );

    sink1->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );
    sink2->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );
    sink3->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );
    sink4->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );
    sink5->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );
    sink6->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("record id=\"%1%\" [\"%2%\"] thread_id= %3% %4%")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< attrs::current_thread_id::value_type >("ThreadID")
        % expr::message
    );

    /*
    // Set header and footer writing functors
    namespace bll = boost::lambda;

    sink->locked_backend()->set_open_handler
    (
        bll::_1 << "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<log>\n"
    );
    sink->locked_backend()->set_close_handler
    (
        bll::_1 << "</log>\n"
    );
    */

    // Add the sink to the core
    //logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
    core->add_sink(sink0);
    core->add_sink(sink1);
    core->add_sink(sink2);
    core->add_sink(sink3);
    core->add_sink(sink4);
    core->add_sink(sink5);
    core->add_sink(sink6);
}
//]

//enum { LOG_RECORDS_TO_WRITE = 2000 };
/*
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        // Initialize logging library
        init_logging();


        // And also add some attributes
        logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", attrs::local_clock());
        logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("RecordID", attrs::counter< unsigned int >());

        // Do some logging
        src::logger lg;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LOG_RECORDS_TO_WRITE; ++i)
        {
            BOOST_LOG(lg) << "XML log record " << i;
        }

        // Test that XML character decoration works
        BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Special XML characters: &, <, >, \", '";

        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "FAILURE: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
*/

/*
*          Copyright Andrey Semashev 2007 - 2015.
* Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
*    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
*          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
*/
/*
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
#if 0

//[ example_tutorial_file_simple
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log("sample.log");

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
//]

// We need this due to this bug: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4416
//[ example_tutorial_file_advanced_no_callouts
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
//]

#else

//[ example_tutorial_file_advanced
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",                                        //*< file name pattern >
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,                                   //*< rotate files every 10 MiB... >
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), //*< ...or at midnight >
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"                                 //*< log record format >
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
//]

#endif
void init_logging()
{
    // Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(
        keywords::file_name = "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.xml",
        keywords::rotation_size = 16384
    ));

    // Set up where the rotated files will be stored
    init_file_collecting(sink);

    // Upon restart, scan the directory for files matching the file_name pattern
    sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();

    sink->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("\t<record id=\"%1%\" timestamp=\"%2%\">%3%</record>")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::xml_decor[expr::stream << expr::smessage]
    );

    // Set header and footer writing functors
    namespace bll = boost::lambda;

    sink->locked_backend()->set_open_handler
    (
        bll::_1 << "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<log>\n"
    );
    sink->locked_backend()->set_close_handler
    (
        bll::_1 << "</log>\n"
    );

    // Add the sink to the core
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}
*/
```

## program_options_1.h

```
#pragma once
//#include "stdafx.h"    
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp" //include all types plus i/o
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "utils.h"

namespace po = boost::program_options;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

po::variables_map init_program_options(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const string  VERSION = "0.2.1";
    try {
        date_duration single_day(1);
        auto facet = new date_input_facet();
        facet->set_iso_extended_format();
        //facet->format("%Y-%m-%d");
        std::locale::global(std::locale(std::locale(), facet));

        std::vector<symbols_enum> symbols_default = { symbols_enum::GBPJPY};

        string prog = "DUKA";

        po::options_description desc(prog + " Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help", "produce help message")
            ("version,v", "outputs Version of program")
            ("day,d", po::value<date>()->default_value(day_clock::universal_day()), "specific day format YYYY-MM-DD (default today)")
            ("startdate,s", po::value<date>()->default_value(day_clock::universal_day() - single_day), "start date format YYYY-MM-DD (default today)")
            ("enddate,e", po::value<date>()->default_value(day_clock::universal_day()), "end date format YYYY-MM-DD (default today)")
            ("thread,t", po::value<int>()->default_value(20), "number of threads (default 20)")
            ("folder,f", po::value<string>()->default_value("."), "destination folder (default .)")
            ("candle,c", po::value<timeframe_enum>()->default_value(timeframe_enum::TICK, "TICK"), "use candles instead of ticks. Accepted values TICK M1 M2 M5 M10 M15 M30 H1 H4")
            ("header", po::value<bool>()->default_value(false), "include CSV header (default false)")
            ("symbols", po::value<std::vector<symbols_enum>>()->multitoken()->composing()->default_value(symbols_default, "GBPJPY"), "symbol list using format EURUSD EURGBP")
            ;
        po::positional_options_description pd;
        pd.add("symbols", -1);

        command_line_parser parser{ argc, argv };
        parser.options(desc).positional(pd);
        parsed_options parsed_options = parser.run();

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(parsed_options, vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            cout << desc << "\n";
            exit(0);
        }

        if (vm.count("version")) {
            cout << VERSION << "\n";
            exit(0);
        }

        if (vm.count("day")) {
            cout << "day set to "
                << vm["day"].as<date>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "day was not set.\n";
        }

        if (vm.count("startdate")) {
            cout << "startdate set to "
                << vm["startdate"].as<date>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "startdate was not set.\n";
        }

        if (vm.count("enddate")) {
            cout << "enddate set to "
                << vm["enddate"].as<date>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "enddate was not set.\n";
        }

        if (vm.count("thread")) {
            cout << "thread set to "
                << vm["thread"].as<int>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "thread was not set.\n";
        }

        if (vm.count("folder")) {
            cout << "folder set to "
                << vm["folder"].as<string>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "folder was not set.\n";
        }

        if (vm.count("candle")) {
            cout << "candle set to "
                << vm["candle"].as<timeframe_enum>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "candle level was not set.\n";
        }



        if (vm.count("header")) {
            cout << "header set to "
                << vm["header"].as<bool>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "header was not set.\n";
        }

        if (vm.count("symbols")) {
            cout << "symbols set to "
                << vm["symbols"].as<std::vector<symbols_enum>>() << ".\n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "symbols was not set.\n";
        }
        return vm;
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    catch (...) {
        cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
    }    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can create loggers anywhere in your program. Maybe you should describe your problem - what you want to do and what doesn't work.

Comment: i edited the question ...thanks alot for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the core and sinks do persist after return and can be used by logmacros defined in c++2.cpp but the loggers dont persist?

Logging core is a singleton created and maintained internally by Boost.Log. When you first call `logging::core::get()` the library creates the core object and returns a pointer to it. Subsequent calls return pointers to the same object. The singleton does not get destroyed until the application terminates. Global and thread-specific attributes are managed by the core.

Sinks are registered in the core, so they also exist until the application terminates or until they are removed from core.

Loggers are not connected to the core, they are separate object that your application creates as needed. Loggers use the logging core to produce log records.

Logging macros don't use the core or sinks directly. All log records are emitted through loggers, which provide source-specific attributes.

You can learn more about how Boost.Log operates from the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/design.html).

Comment: thanks for ur reply....this means that i cant make loggers outside the main function right????.....and in turn if i wanted to change sink file directories of log during the program i ll have to close the logging core and reinitialize with the new directory of logs in the sink then re-register it in the new core...am i right?...cant i declare loggers as static or any other idea you suggest so that i just use macros in main......can i return the loggers from init_logging().....by the way ur explanation is soooooooo wonderful tackleing directly the problem in my mind"singleton need studied"

Comment: *this means that i cant make loggers outside the main function right?* No, you can create loggers anywhere you want. For global loggers you can create them in namespace scope or use the specialized facility documented here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.global_storage

Comment: *if i wanted to change sink file directories of log during the program i ll have to close the logging core and reinitialize with the new directory of logs in the sink then re-register it in the new core* You can't create a new core, it is a singleton (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). To change the target log files config you can use the sink backend API (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.html) or just remove the old sink and create and register a new one.

Comment: *can i return the loggers from init_logging()* Yes, although you don't have to.

Comment: thank you for ur reply...ill study the singleton then will try to return loggers from the init_logging function